# File text replacement

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I have a small issue and i hope your your help.

The problem is as fallow:
I need to track a huge log and more exactly a column.
In this column i have some integer values in a rage between 103 and 17430.
Example of original file

```
....
402
402
402
402
402
402
402
402
402
1917
402
402
402
402
402
667
942
342
990
444
.....
```

I must replace  each row of my original file with an alternative index number.

Example:

```
....
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
7
3
3
3
3
9
5
3
1
....
```

Initially i tried to use `sed` in order to look for my string and replace it accordingly. First I extract only the data that i need then I start replacing:

```
col1=$(csvtool col 2  /mypath/log.csv >index )
 sed -i 's/103/3 /g' index
 sed -i 's/104/3 /g' index
 sed -i 's/105/3 /g' index
 sed -i 's/106/3 /g' index
........................
```

The problem is that it takes way to long to perform the changes due to large file and clearly inefficient method.

I was thinking to do something like:

```
csvtool col 2  /mypath/log.csv >index    
for X in range (103 , 106 ) or (306-997):
      print (3)
    done < index
```

My problem is that I not proficient with loops (yet). I`m isolating the data that I need  by creating the index file and I must read each row for my X value.  My indexes are on specific ,sometimes multiple, ranges of my X values. Index number 3 can be taken by any X between 103 and 106 but 306-997 also.

In order to speed up the process I was thinking to use the loops and fit my X into a specific range, rather then comparing with each possible value. Any help how can I write my loops? or you have a better idea?

With the help of Cyrus I manage to write the fallowing corrected code:

```
csvtool col 2  /my/path/to/List.csv >tmp 


awk '($0>=363 && $0<=499) || ($0>=4645 && $0<=4646) {$0="0"}1' tmp 

awk '($0>=2174 && $0<=2193)  {$0="1"}1' tmp 

awk '($0=500) || ($0>=12308 && $0<=12356) {$0="2"}1' tmp 

awk '($0>=103 && $0<=220) || ($0>=252 && $0<=299) || ($0>=1980 && $0<=1986) || ($0>=2921 && $0<=2922) {$0="3"}1' tmp 

awk '($0>=221 && $0<=251) || ($0>=8085 && $0<=8091) || ($0=8350) || ($0>=12809 && $0<=12945) || ($0>=16834 && $0<=17033)  {$0="4"}1' tmp 

awk '($0>=300 && $0<=362) || ($0=522) || ($0>=2923 && $0<=2925) || ($0>=3441 && $0<=3442) || ($0=4644)|| ($0>=5677 && $0<=5695) || ($0>=8082 && $0<=8083)|| ($0>=8093 && $0<=8349) || ($0>=12946 && $0<=12947) || ($0>=21986 && $0<=13215) || ($0>=13309 && $0<=13311)  {$0="5"}1' tmp 

awk '($0>=501 && $0<=504) || ($0>=566 && $0<=600) || ($0>=613 && $0<=637) ||  ($0>=2015 && $0<=2040) ||  ($0>=2103 && $0<=2126) || ($0>=2373 && $0<=2374) || ($0>=3828 && $0<=4125) || ($0>=4237 && $0<=4636) || ($0>=4647 && $0<=4889) || ($0>=4991 && $0<=5676) || ($0>=5696 && $0<=5705) || ($0>=6502 && $0<=6595) || ($0>=8429 && $0<=8460) || ($0>=8552 && $0<=8699) || ($0>=10487 && $0<=10977) || ($0>=11326 && $0<=11617) || ($0>=11688 && $0<=11815) || ($0>=11844 && $0<=11938) || ($0>=12490 && $0<=12597) || ($0>=12973 && $0<=12982) || ($0>=13367 && $0<=13414)  {$0="6"}1' tmp 


awk '($0>=523 && $0<=548) || ($0>=555 && $0<=565) || ($0>=2005 && $0<=2014) || ($0>=2041 && $0<=2063) || ($0>=2091 && $0<=2102) ||  ($0=2394) || ($0>=2407 && $0<=2411) || ($0>=2926 && $0<=3008) || ($0>=3443 && $0<=3473) || ($0>=3486 && $0<=3813) || ($0>=4132 && $0<=4144) || ($0>=4637 && $0<=4643) || ($0>=4916 && $0<=4981) || ($0>=5711 && $0<=5741) || ($0>=6403 && $0<=6405) || ($0>=6415 && $0<=6466) || ($0>=6701 && $0<=7002) || ($0>=7035 && $0<=7048) || ($0>=8426 && $0<=8428) || ($0>=8496 && $0<=8541) || ($0>=8857 && $0<=9323) || ($0>=9429 && $0<=9618) || ($0>=9674 && $0<=9789) || ($0>=9802 && $0<=9811) || ($0>=9850 && $0<=10009) || ($0>=10131 && $0<=10136) || ($0>=10396 && $0<=10402) || ($0>=11000 && $0<=11175) || ($0=11618) || ($0>=12100 && $0<=12111) || ($0>=12212 && $0<=12219) || ($0=12489) || ($0>=12807 && $0<=12808) || ($0=12983) || ($0>=14616 && $0<=14627) || ($0>=15723 && $0<=15897) {$0="7"}1' tmp 

awk '($0=521) || ($0=554) || ($0>=601 && $0<=612) || ($0>=651 && $0<=708) || ($0>=1905 && $0<=1942) || ($0>=1949 && $0<=1979) || ($0>=1987 && $0<=1993) || ($0>=2259 && $0<=2278) || ($0>=2352 && $0<=2362) || ($0>=2395 && $0<=2406) || ($0>=2412 && $0<=2449) || ($0>=2673 && $0<=2919) || ($0>=3009 && $0<=3016) || ($0>=3814 && $0<=3827) || ($0>=4126 && $0<=4131) || ($0>=4982 && $0<=4990) || ($0>=5706 && $0<=5710) || ($0>=6012 && $0<=6181) || ($0>=6285 && $0<=6339) || ($0>=6409 && $0<=6411) || ($0>=6596 && $0<=6700) || ($0>=7191 && $0<=7424) || ($0=8081) || ($0>=8550 && $0<=8551) || ($0>=8700 && $0<=8716) || ($0>=9324 && $0<=9326) || ($0>=9619 && $0<=9624) || ($0=9729) || ($0>=10018 && $0<=10064) || ($0>=10115 && $0<=10126) || ($0>=10198 && $0<=10386) || ($0=10486) || ($0>=12112 && $0<=12115) || ($0>=12209 && $0<=12211) {$0="8"}1'  tmp 

awk '($0>=489 && $0<=498) || ($0>=505 && $0<=520) || ($0>=549 && $0<=553) || ($0>=638 && $0<=650) || ($0>=709 && $0<=1904) || ($0>=1943 && $0<=1948) || ($0>=1994 && $0<=2004) || ($0>=2064 && $0<=2090) || ($0>=2127 && $0<=2173) || ($0>=2194 && $0<=2258) || ($0>=2279 && $0<=2351) || ($0>=2363 && $0<=2372) || ($0=2393) || ($0>=2450 && $0<=2672) || ($0>=3474 && $0<=3485) || ($0>=4145 && $0<=4236) || ($0>=4890 && $0<=4915) || ($0>=5742 && $0<=6011) || ($0>=7003 && $0<=7034) || ($0>=7049 && $0<=7295) || ($0>=7425 && $0<=8080) || ($0=8084) || ($0>=8352 && $0<=8425) || ($0>=8461 && $0<=8495) || ($0>=8542 && $0<=8549) || ($0>=8717 && $0<=8856) || ($0>=9327 && $0<=9428) || ($0>=9625 && $0<=9673) || ($0>=9790 && $0<=9791) || ($0>=9793 && $0<=9801) || ($0>=9812 && $0<=9849) || ($0>=10010 && $0<=10017) || ($0>=10065 && $0<=10114) || ($0>=10128 && $0<=10130) || ($0>=10137 && $0<=10197) || ($0>=10387 && $0<=10395) || ($0>=10403 && $0<=10485) || ($0>=10978 && $0<=10999) || ($0>=11176 && $0<=11325) || ($0>=11620 && $0<=11687) || ($0>=11816 && $0<=11843) || ($0>=11939 && $0<=12099) || ($0>=12116 && $0<=12208) || ($0>=12220 && $0<=12307) || ($0>=12357 && $0<=12488) || ($0>=12598 && $0<=12806) || ($0>=12948 && $0<=12972) || ($0>=13216 && $0<=13306) || ($0>=13312 && $0<=13366) || ($0>=13415 && $0<=14615) || ($0>=14628 && $0<=15722) || ($0>=15989 && $0<=16833) || ($0>=17402 && $0<=17431) {$0="9"}1' tmp
```

Unfortunately the output is all "9". Any help?

Comment: can you help me with your idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '($0>=103 && $0<=106) || ($0>=306 && $0<=977) {$0="3"}1' file
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
1917
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
990
3
```

Comment: any idea how to write the output into a  separate file? Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Append `> new_file`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the stupid quiescence, I was tired and I miss type something. Thank you once again for all the help.